# How can I return vector by reference in C++

Tags: c++, vector, pass-by-reference

I want to make the function that returns a vector by reference. But the returned vector(`returned_v`) is not same as `vec.v`, but a copied vector. It means the vector is returned by value.  How can I get the referenced vector from `vector_reference()`?

```
class Vec {
  public:
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<int>& vector_reference() {
        return v;
    }
};

int main() {
    Vec vec;
    std::vector<int> returned_v = vec.vector_reference();
    returned_v.clear();
    std::cout << returned_v.size() << std::endl; // result: 0
    std::cout << vec.v.size() << std::endl; // result: 3

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Except from solving the problem at hand, what's  the purpose? Training?

Comment: The code is a simplified version to make the problem clear. vector_reference() is for returning one of the member vectors according to the status of an instance.

Comment: Ok. I didn't get the problem description.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`returned_v` is an independent object which gets copied from the return value of `vec.vector_reference()`. You should declare it as reference too.

```
std::vector<int>& returned_v = vec.vector_reference();
```

Answer (score 0):

The reference in the function `vector_reference()` is the reference of `vec.v`. However, `returned_v` is a copy of `vec.v`, not a referrence of it. Two ways can help you:

1. `std::vector<int>& returned_v = vec.vector_reference();`
2. `std::vector<int> returned_v = std::move(vec.vector_reference());  //C++ 11`

Comment: Note that in #1, `returned_v` is an alias for `vec.v` itself, whereas in #2, `returned_v` is a separate object that steals ownership of `vec.v`'s data. Subtle but important difference.